# Distinguish between http and https requests in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site which (for legacy reasons) can be access with both http and https.

How do I see in Google Analytics how many users visit with each protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass this information in a custom dimension (hit level), then you can use it in the reports.